# Dynamic JOIN in LINQ in Silverlight and WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, linq, join, dynamic

I need to perform a dynamic `LINQ JOIN` query. Dynamic means, that the number of columns on which I am going to join is not known before the runtime. I don't even know which relation (table) will be on the left/right side of the join. Finally, I don't know the type of join before the program execution (`INNER/OUTER`). A lot of flexibility, a lot of problems.

In WPF it is possible to compile a `string` to `LINQ` statement. It isn't that easy in the case of Silverlight (missing `Microsoft.CSharp` namespace).

I believe that the easiest way to solve the problem would be to compile a string to LINQ. Now I am not sure about that, since I want to have working solutions for both WPF and Silverlight. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the clues.

Comment: There is no outer join in LINQ. And out of interest, how are you compiling string to LINQ statement?

Comment: @svick, how about: from a in A join b in B on new { a.k } equals new { k = b.c } into C from x in C.DefaultIfEmpty() select...? In such a way I can still obtain an outer join.

Comment: @svick, there is an open source compiler (LINQ Compiler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, maybe it isn't nice to respond to your own question, but I solved my problem in a different way, by defining an additional class containing objects from both sides of  `join`. Then, the comparison of these is done with the overriden `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods. Works like a charm in my case:-)

Thanks for the responses anyway.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is really more intended for compile time query than runtime. The pain of building expressions can surpass the funcionality you may be trying to achieve.

If you are doing LINQ to Databases, consider using EF and EntitySql rather than LINQ as you just need to build the entity query as a string and use that rather than trying to build up expression trees at runtime.

Comment: How about the dynamic LINQ? Do you think it would be possible to achieve the functionality with that?

Comment: I haven't worked much with the Dynamic LINQ libraries at this point, but would wonder how you would specify the return type (T in IEnumerable<T>) using it when you don't know the columns at compile time. I assume you would be using IEnumerable<dynamic>. With EntitySql, you can parse strings and consume a DbDataRecord through `context.CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(entitySQL)`.

Comment: Why do you assume that I don't know the return type? It is going to be, say, FlattenedType having the columns specified in select statement.

Comment: But at compile time do you know what those columns will be (so that you can assign a known type - class) or is the user choosing at runtime which columns they want? .Select<T> needs you to tell it what type to create (including anonymous types which the compiler generates at compile time). If you don't know the columns at compile time, you're dealing with a dynamic type situation and in that case DbDataRecord makes perfect sense.